# VLOOKUP Excel: comparing columns

Tags: excel-formula, office365, formula

I am trying to do a very simple task that does not give me the expected results:

I got the following excel table with columns A and B:

Column A
Mr. John Doh
Mario Bros
Dr. Frankenstein
Mickey Mouse
Donald Duck

Column B
Jenny Dart
john doh
Roger Rabbit
Frankenstein

I am extracting values with VLOOKUP comparing B to A

`=VLOOKUP("*"&B1&"*";$A$1:$A$5;1;FALSE)`

however the result is the following:

Mr. John Doh
#N/A
#N/A
#N/A

If I do the contrary so comparing A to B:

`=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*";$B$1:$B$5;1;FALSE)`

I get the following result:

#N/A
#N/A
#N/A
Dr. Frankenstein

In both cases I would expect to see "Dr.Frankenstein" and "Mr.John Doh" appearing in both results
however, it seems not the case.

Any idea why?
There are no extra spaces in the cells
There are no Typos in the cells.
I tested the index 1 and the index 2 with no luck.
TRUE cannot be used as I am having "*"

The ultimate goal is to have a long list of users and pulling out data comparing the columns considering that some cells contain title+name like: "Mr." or "Dr."

Answer (score 0):

In the A column you have "Mr. John Doh" and in B "john doh" so when using Vlookup to search *john doh* in A, it finds it. But in case you are searching "Mr. John Doh" it can't be successful because of the "Mr. " part of the string.
The same case with Frankenstein and Dr. Frankenstein in the other example. Strip the titles ("Dr", Mr. etc) and it will work.

Comment: But the wildcards and the FALSE to my undeerstanding should match any...result containing the name... I m still confused